# Could libgdx's adapter classes be avoided?

Tags: java, interface, libgdx

Hello!

I'm a beginner programmer currently learning the Java language and the libgdx API. Today, I've been studying about *interfaces* and its usages. To better understand the subject, I've looked for libgdx's interfaces and some of its implementations. I found out that there are some abstract classes called "adapters" that basically implements an interface, making it more convenient for the user that wishes to use that interface to just extend the adapter class, in order to avoid having to implement undesired methods from the interface (see [ApplicationAdapter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationAdapter.html), [ScreenAdapter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ScreenAdapter.html) and [InputAdapter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputAdapter.html)).

**My question is: since JDK 8 introduced *default methods implementation*, are libgdx's adapter classes now unnecessary?** If the methods from the interfaces implemented by these adapters had a default implementation (that could even be an empty body), then there would be no reason to use the adapters.

Note that by asking this question I, in no way, want to criticize libgdx's devs. I'm also aware that libgdx was developed before default methods implementation was allowed by Java. I'm just a beginner trying to better understand interfaces and how to properly use them. Thank you!

Comment: It wouldn't be the proper use of `default`. Not implementing methods declared in an `interface` suggests that interface is too broad & should be segregated. But this may require deprecation, which conjures many other issues (Can we safely remove the deprecated member in the future, or keep the member for legacy apps & keep the bloat?). I doubt the API designers have any intentions for defaulting in these cases, as it's not only against the philosophy of interfaces (having *all* default methods), but there are far bigger problems to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of opinion.

Yes, with Java 8's default methods for interfaces the convenience achieved by the adapter classes could have been included directly in the interface.

But the authors of **libGDX** could also have excluded the interfaces all together and just have used the adapter classes. Or they could have made the adapter classes abstract with concrete implementations for all the methods.

As the adapter classes are there just for convenience (for example, see the `ScreenAdapter` javadoc:

> convenience implementation of {@link Screen}. Derive from this and only override what you need.

), there are a number of ways to achieve the same. I think default methods for interfaces were primarily added to be able to extend an interface with more methods without breaking existing implementations. Look below, from [Interface Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html):

> Default methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces of your libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written for older versions of those interfaces.

However, they could also be used to provide convenience methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can see now that what the *libgdx*'s authors did is just a matter of taste.